# Pandas dataframe column selection

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to select columns from a dataframe, olddf. Let's say the variable names are 'a', 'b','c', 'starswith1', 'startswith2', 'startswith3',...,'startswith10'.

My approach was to create a list of all variables with a common starting value.

```
    filter_col = [col for col in list(health) if col.startswith('startswith')]
```

I'd like to then select columns within that list as well as others, by name, so I don't have to type them all out. However, this doesn't work:

```
newdf = olddf['a','b',filter_col]
```

And this doesn't either:

```
newdf = olddf[['a','b'],filter_col]
```

I'm a newbie so this is probably pretty simple. Is the reason this doesn't work because I'm mixing a list improperly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
newdf = olddf[['a','b']+filter_col]
```

since adding lists concatenates them:

```
In [264]: ['a', 'b'] + ['startswith1']
Out[264]: ['a', 'b', 'startswith1']
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [the `filter` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
newdf = olddf.filter(regex=r'^(startswith|[ab])')
```